# What does "to put it up to the favourite" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, verbs, phrasal-verbs

The sentence is "Ground permitting, he is going to put it up to the favourite."

I looked this up and found that it is mostly used in horse racing contexts. Does it mean to challenge the most favoured competitor?

Please help!

Comment: Where did you read the original sentence?

Comment: Without more Details , I would assume that when the race takes place (eg no rain or not getting cancelled Etc) he would **"bet"** on the favourite horse or the horse which is the bookmakers favourite.

Comment: @KillingTime I was given this sentence in isolation to translate into another language. But Google tells me it come from https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/motivated-for-the-challenge-dm9kdzmmmkn. If I look up just "to put it up to the favourite", I see mostly racing-related results.

Comment: @Prem Your reasoning seems sound. But see https://www.independent.ie/sport/horse-racing/mercurial-harchibald-poised-to-make-a-winning-return-26367598.html, where Essex (who I assume is a horse) is putting it up to the favourite. As a non-native speaker, I am unable to understand.

Comment: Without more Details , there can be various meanings , including that in my earlier comment. Even within horse racing , it might mean betting on (putting money on), challenging (put up a tight contest), attribute , support , Etc. The Crux or Core is (1) what "it" refers to (2) which meaning of "put" or "put up" is involved. In the Example in your Post , I still go with betting. In the "Independent" , it means to challenge. In the "Times" , I have no access , unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, @Prem. I, too, cannot access The Times. I wish there were a way to get more context. Translating this in isolation is a task. :/

Comment: Not part of my vocabulary (and also I am American), but "put it up to" is probably going to be "compete favorably against" and "the favorite" is going to be the horse people expect to win. In the link @valess offered above, Essex is a horse who "has the talent" to compete favorably against Harchibald.

Comment: Thanks, @Yorik.